# Calling simplemodal jumps to the homescreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

Am trying to open up an image in a modal. So far everything is working good.
Just having one problem.

Am having a homescreen with tabs in the footer.
Now one tab opens up `content/index.html`
So like, the page opens as `index.html#content/index.html`

Am loading a modal onclick of an image in the content/index.html file with

```
onclick = "$('#basic-modal-content').modal();"
```

Now, this opens the modal well, but it opens on the homescreen rather than on the same screen.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have `href="#"` then you need to prevent default browser behavior which is jump to id with # or if the id is not there jump to top:

```
onclick="$('#basic-modal-content').modal(); return false;"
```

but you should not use onclick attribute insitead use jQuery click function:

```
$('your link selector').click(function(e) {
   $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
   return false; // or e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! That sorted it out! :)